# LARAVEL 5.5: How to optimally add an array to the database?

Tags: php, arrays, database, laravel, laravel-5.5

I've 2 tables in my database. My first table, table with words:

Structure table "**words**":

```
--------------
[id] | [word]
--------------
[11] | [тоҷик]
[12] | [ӯзбек]
[13] | [падар]
[14] | [модар]
[15] | [китоб]
[16] | [қалам]
[17] | [ручка]
--------------
```

Second table, table with descriptions:

Structure table "**descriptions**":

```
---------------------------------------
[id] | [word_id] | [description]
---------------------------------------
[1]  | [11]      | [Миллати давлати...]
[2]  | [12]      | [Ӯзбекистон давл...]
[3]  | [13]      | [Шахсе ки сарвар...]
[4]  | [14]      | [Инсоне мобошанд...]
[5]  | [15]      | [Китоб - ин пред...]
[6]  | [16]      | [Предмети барои ...]
[7]  | [17]      | [Предмет барои н...]
---------------------------------------
```

Example of description words in an array:

```
$array_words_description = array
(
    'тоҷик' => 'Миллати давлати Ҷумҳурии Тоҷикистон. Забони давлати мазкур.',
    'ӯзбек' => 'Ӯзбекистон давлати дар Осиёи маркази ҷойгиршуда. Забони давлатиашон забони ӯзбеки мебошад.',
    'падар' => 'Шахсе ки сарвари оила мебошад ва оилаи худро бо меҳру муҳаббат ва бо хӯрду - хӯрок таъмин менамояд.',
    'модар' => 'Инсоне мобошанд, ки мову шуморо ба дунё оварда ба воя мерасонанд. Бузургтарин шахс дар олам ин модар аст.',
    'китоб' => 'Китоб - ин предмете, ки ба ҳамаи мо илму маърифатро, донишу сабақро меомӯзонад.',
    'қалам' => 'Предмети барои нашитаҷот пешбинишуда.',
    'ручка' => 'Предмет барои навистан пешбини шудааст. Бисёртар ин предметро донишомӯзандагон истифода мебаранд.',
);
```

How to add this description to the `description` table by adding the word identifier in the array key from the `word` table to the `word_id` field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
foreach ($array_words_description as $word => $description) {
    $word = Word::create(['word' => $word]);
    $word->description()->create(['description' => $description]);
}
```

It'll work is you'll add column names in  `$fillable` array and define `description` relationship in the `Word` model.

But I'd recommend you to use just one table for both word and its description and insert data with just one query instead of creating N*2 number of queries:

```
array_walk(&$array_words_description, function ($word, $description) {
    return compact('word', 'description');
});

Word::insert($array_words_description);
```

Comment: +1 for answer @Alex Mezenin. For my project need first method. But when I add `protected $fillable = ['description'];` in Word model end execute take this error: `"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'word' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `words` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2017-10-22 20:42:14, 2017-10-22 20:42:14))` The code can not find the `word` field to add value. Because in filleable passed another field. Can I specify both fields in the `$fillable`? How to add more than one field to a `$fillable` variable?

Comment: You need to use `word` for `Word` model and `description` for `Description` model.

Comment: And what if there are words in the database that I want to add from the array but without a description? Fields contain an index to avoid duplication of words. @Alex Mezenin

Comment: The query will give an error due to the existence of the value being added.

Comment: And the description will not be added. I'm right? @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: Use `firstOrCreate()` instead of `create()` or you don't want to create duplicates. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#other-creation-methods

Comment: If there is a word but without a description then will the description for the same word from my array be added if I use the recommended method? @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: @John I guess it's better to create another question and specify all the logic you need there (all cases). In this case, me or someone else will be able to give you advice.

Comment: Yes, of course, but in this answer in the first reduced method, you did not understand me correctly. All is added to both tables, but the `id` of the current added word is not added from table `'words'` field `'id'` to the `"description"` table in the `"word_id"` field. Because this operation  is not specified in your first method adding. @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: This is necessary in order for such queries to work to return an exact description of the current (entered) word, like this: `SELECT description FROM words_descriptions WHERE words.id = word_id`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't have any relations in your eloquent model classes
You can achieve what you want by doing like this

```
$word_id = DB::table('words')->insertGetId(['word' => $word]);
DB::table('descriptions')->insert(['word_id' => $word_id, 'description' => $description]);
```

Comment: Nice. What is your approach to the index field? If we add a new word to the same array and move it at the end of the array, then the error occurs with duplication due to the polyex and no new words are added. Is it possible to solve this with the help of the method `updateOrInsert()` with `insertGetId()` ? @mirage_909